# Binding a javascript function with null or undefined as thisArg

Tags: javascript, function, null, undefined, currying

When I execute the following javascript snippet ...

```
function addAndThis(n1, n2) {
  console.log("THIS:" + this + " SUM:" + (n1+n2));
}

var boundNullThisAddAndThis = addAndThis.bind(null);
var boundUndefinedThisddAndThis = addAndThis.bind(undefined);
var boundStringThisAddAndThis = addAndThis.bind("TEST");

addAndThis(10, 20);
boundNullThisAddAndThis(100, 200);
boundUndefinedThisddAndThis(1000, 2000);
boundStringThisAddAndThis(10000, 20000);
```

... I get this output:

```
THIS:[object Window] SUM:30
THIS:[object Window] SUM:300
THIS:[object Window] SUM:3000
THIS:TEST SUM:30000
```

The first and last line of the output is as I expected. But why does the bound function created by **Function.prototype.bind** does not call the wrapped function with a this of null or undefined? I did not find anything about this behaviour on the net.

Comment: When you add "use strict"; at the beginning of function, it behaves as expected, so maybe null/undefined are translated to window by default unless strict mode is in play?

Comment: Yes, if you bind to null or undefined it means the global context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely some issue with trying to use a non-object as a context. Trying to use a primitive (`fn.call(1)`) actually "boxes" the value, turning the primitive into an object for use as the context.

The `.call()` `.apply()` and `.bind()` functions all take "nully" values and uses the default `window` object instead.

As others have pointed out (and on the MDN page also), this does not happen in strict mode. Strangely, while most of the time strict mode puts kid gloves on you, in this case it trusts you know what you're doing! ;P

[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)]

Comment: As others have pointed out (and on the MDN page also), this does not happen in strict mode. Strangely, while most of the time strict mode puts kid gloves on you, in this case it trusts you know what you're doing! ;P

Comment: var boundStringThisAddAndThis = addAndThis.bind("TEST"); why it returned THIS:TEST SUM:30 , TEST is just string not object ?